# How to check for existing interaction in discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I began working on my discord bot few days ago, and while creating my rps (rock, paper, scissors) command I encountered a minor problem, when I run the command twice without finishing the game my bot crushes. Here's my code:

```
 module.exports = {
    name: 'rps',
    cooldown: 0,
    aliases: [],
    permissions: [],
    description: 'Rock Paper Scissors.',
    async execute(message, args, client, Discord) {
        let hand = [{ txt: 'Rock', emoji: '✊', index: 0 }, { txt: 'Paper', emoji: '', index: 1 }, { txt: 'Scissors', emoji: '✌️', index: 2 }]; // Defining Moves
        let botMove = hand[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]; // Making a random move

        let rpsMsg = await message.channel.send({ // Prompting user to make a move
            embeds: [
                new Discord.MessageEmbed() // RPS embed
                    .setColor('RANDOM')
                    .setTitle('Rock Paper Scissors')
                    .setDescription('Choose a handsign')
            ],
            components: [
                new Discord.MessageActionRow() // Rock, paper, scissors buttons
                    .addComponents(
                        new Discord.MessageButton()
                            .setCustomId(`rps_rock`)
                            .setLabel("✊ Rock")
                            .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
                        new Discord.MessageButton()
                            .setCustomId(`rps_paper`)
                            .setLabel(" Paper")
                            .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
                        new Discord.MessageButton()
                            .setCustomId(`rps_scissors`)
                            .setLabel("✌️ Scissors")
                            .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                    )
            ]
        });

        let win = 0; // 0 = Loss; 1 = Tie; 2 = Win
        let userMove;
        
        // If you already / want to handle this in your interactionCreate.js, ignore this part.
        
        let f = async (interaction) => {
            if (!interaction.isButton()) return; // Checking if the interaction is a button
            if (interaction.customId.startsWith('rps')) {
                await interaction.deferUpdate() // Deffering the interaction
                let move = interaction.customId.split('_')[1]
                userMove = hand.find(v => v.txt.toLowerCase() == move)
                switch (move) { // Calculating if player wins, losses, or a tie
                    case 'rock':
                        win = botMove.index == 0 ? 1 : (botMove.index == 1 ? 0 : 2); break;
                    case 'paper':
                        win = botMove.index == 0 ? 2 : (botMove.index == 1 ? 1 : 0); break;
                    case 'scissors':
                        win = botMove.index == 0 ? 0 : (botMove.index == 1 ? 2 : 1); break;
                }

                let embed = rpsMsg.embeds[0];
                // Editing the embed
                embed.description = `I chose ${botMove.txt}! ${win == 0 ? 'You lost!' : (win == 1 ? 'We tied!' : 'You win!')} (${userMove.emoji} ${win == 0 ? '<' : (win == 1 ? '=' : '>')} ${botMove.emoji})`;
                
                let components = rpsMsg.components
                // Disabling all buttons
                components[0].components.forEach(comp => {
                    if (comp.customId == interaction.customId) { comp.disabled = true; comp.style = 'SECONDARY' }
                    else comp.disabled = true
                })
                
                // Editing the message
                interaction.message.edit({ embeds: [embed], components: components })
                
                // Removing this event.
                client.off('interactionCreate', f)
            }
        }

        client.on('interactionCreate', f) // Creates the event
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to check for an existing interaction or to delete it so my bot wont crush?
BTW, that's the terminal's output:

````
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\bar_m\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\bar_m\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async ButtonInteraction.deferUpdate (C:\Users\bar_m\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:185:5)
    at async Client.f (C:\Users\bar_m\Desktop\DiscordBot\commands\rps.js:45:17) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/interactions/996846575148081182/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246OTk2ODQ2NTc1MTQ4MDgxMTgyOm1lOUhSNzhYY2JVcm8yYzk3S056UmJHdG5SNTZOQ0ZDQVlTVXMyZnNralVlc2l0bGNPYm8zUFNJaWFEY0hHTXpTT043TUZkUHc2ckNJRDJ5ZnVEY2o0RFZvVTQ4QUw1UURQODYybndFSzBRTE5pb0ROQ0VyNHdmdmt3MXdSU3U5/callback',
  code: 40060,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: { json: { type: 6 }, files: [] }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

`client.on('interactionCreate', f)` is not what you need here. This results in any interaction the client receives being routed only to your function `f`, which can cause problems receiving interactions with your client.

Probably the best thing to use here is `message.createMessageComponentCollector(...)`, check [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=createMessageComponentCollector) (discord.js docs) for more information.
You can add the following code instead of `client.on('interactionCreate', f)`:

```
    const filter = (interaction) => interaction.customId.startsWith("rps"); // Only handle interactions whose id start with "rps"
    const collector = rpsMsg.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter }); // Create a messageComponentCollector on the rps message
    collector.on("collect", (interaction) => f(interaction)); // Execute the `f` function when a button is clicked
```

Using a component collector, you won't need to run `client.off('interactionCreate', f)`, so you can remove that from your code as well.